# Child Actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions Partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

On my Main View I have 4 partial views.. two are tables.. the others are create forms.

**Partial View Table 1**

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.code_AutoMake>

<h3>Auto Make List</h3>
<table id="Auto-Make-Table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-5">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AutoMake)
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-5">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Active)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AutoMake)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
                </td>
                @if (!item.Active)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MakeID }) |
                        <a href="#" class="text-info js-automake-activate" data-automake-id="@item.MakeID" data-automake-name="@item.AutoMake">Activate</a>
                    </td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MakeID }) |
                        <a href="#" class="text-danger js-automake-delete" data-automake-id="@item.MakeID" data-automake-name="@item.AutoMake">Deactivate</a>
                    </td>
                }

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Partial View Table 2**

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.code_Funding>

<h3>Funding List</h3>
<table class="table table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Funding)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Active)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Funding)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "code_Funding",new { id=item.FundID }, null) |
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**Partial View  1 Create**

```
@model ProjectName.Models.code_AutoMake

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "code_AutoMake", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h3>Add Auto Make</h3>
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                @Html.Label("Auto Make")
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AutoMake, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                @Html.Label("Active")
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Partial View 2 Create**

```
@model ProjectName.Models.code_Funding

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "code_Funding", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h3>Add Funding</h3>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                @Html.Label("Funding")
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Funding, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                @Html.Label("Active")
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Main View**

```
<div id="AutoMake" class="tab-pane fade active in">
    <div id="AutoMake-Index">@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "code_AutoMake");}</div>
    <hr/>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Create", "code_AutoMake");}
</div>
@*Funding*@
<div id="Funding" class="tab-pane fade">
    @{Html.RenderAction("Index", "code_Funding");}
    <hr/>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Create", "code_Funding");}
</div>
```

Now here is the scenario.. When I want to create a new `autoMake`.. I fill out the form and hit submit.. this goes through fine.. until I get back to the Main View.. specifically this line:

`@{Html.RenderAction("Create", "code_Funding");}`

and I get a runtime error saying:

> Child Actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions

I have debugged.. and for some reason.. the `HttpPost Create` action for `code_Funding` is being hit.. even when I'm not filling out the create form for code_funding.. How is that possible?

Here are my Create Methods for code_autoMake and code_funding:

**code_Funding**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FundID,Funding,Active")] code_Funding code_Funding)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.code_Funding.Add(code_Funding);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("EditDDL", "tblNewAutos");
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("EditDDL", "tblNewAutos");
    }
```

**code_autoMake**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MakeID,AutoMake,Active")] code_AutoMake code_AutoMake)
    {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.code_AutoMake.Add(code_AutoMake);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return PartialView("~/Views/PartialViews/_AutoMakeCreate.cshtml");
            }


        return RedirectToAction("EditDDL", "tblNewAutos");
    }
```

Why when I try and create a new automake.. both HttpPost Create methods are hit?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "create a new automake" but this is the line which causes that your Create method is hit: `@{Html.RenderAction("Create", "code_Funding");}` and this one as well `@{Html.RenderAction("Create", "code_AutoMake");}`. The `@{Html.RenderAction(...)` method calls the action and inserts its resulting view into the parent view from which the child action was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is following. In your main view you have got this code:

```
...
@{Html.RenderAction("Create", "code_AutoMake");}
...
```

Which triggers the `Create` action which finishes with the following line of code if `ModelState.IsValid == false`:

```
return RedirectToAction("EditDDL", "tblNewAutos");
```

That is obviously a bad idea. Why? You are already in a process of rendering a parent view. Child actions might be a bit confusing at first because they are not real actions - no client/server communication. You are still on the server side. Therefore no redirect is allowed in the child action.

### Solutions

First of all, I am not quite sure what you want to achieve so my solution recommendation might be a bit off, but let's see.

#### Option 1

You may want to use two different actions. One that is called on submit of the form and another one that is called from your main view. The latter one should not make a redirect - instead it should wisely choose which view to render based on the `ModelState.IsValid` if this is really what you need.

#### Option 2

There is a hack way which allows you to make redirect from a child action. Instead of making a redirect, only store information about required redirect for instance in `HttpContext.Items` collection. Then, implement an ActionFilter and in its `OnResultExecuted` event, check if the redirect request was set to the `HttpContext.Items`. If so, make a redirect. The `ActionFilter` should be applied on the parent action, not on the child action.

Comment: Lol sorry but I think I'm more confused now haha

Comment: What about calling the view in the action method?  like `return View("EditDDL")`

Comment: I think I found the cause.. let me repost my question

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid, well, sorry for causing confusion. Simply, you have to avoid any redirects in child actions. What is a child action? In your case it is the Create action triggered by calling `Html.RenderAction` from your main view.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Create", "code_Funding");}
```

in this RenderAction Method is call the GET request but, your controller you written only post method. and you write the

```
[ChildActionOnly]  
public ActionResult Create(string parm)
{
 reurn view()
}
```

and use  [ChildActionOnly] this attribute is allowing restricted access via code in View.

Check and reply me..

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe that within child action call, the GET/POST attributes do not matter at all. So the attribute is not a problem. The problem is the redirect within the child action.